# What information is contained in the NTFS metadata?

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs

I want to know what information is contained in the NTFS metadata.
But I couldn't find the paper anywhere.

I guess the metadata has a filename, a size and an attributes etc.
Has NTFS metadata also got a Shortpath name?
What information is contained in the NTFS metadata?

Do you know a good site or a page about this? If you do, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Windows Internals 5th Edition, Chapter 11 File System, this book explains NTFS structure and metadata in detail.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple NTFS meta files but the one you want regarding files is $MFT, the file table

From [ntfs.com](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-files-types.htm):

**Standard Information**
Includes information such as timestamp and link count.

**Attribute List**
Lists the location of all attribute records that do not fit in the MFT record.

**File Name**
A repeatable attribute for both long and short file names. The long name of the file can be up to 255 Unicode characters. The short name is the 8.3, case-insensitive name for the file. Additional names, or hard links, required by POSIX can be included as additional file name attributes.

**Security Descriptor** 
Describes who owns the file and who can access it.

**Data**
Contains file data. NTFS allows multiple data attributes per file. Each file typically has one unnamed data attribute. A file can also have one or more named data attributes, each using a particular syntax.

**Object ID**
A volume-unique file identifier. Used by the distributed link tracking service. Not all files have object identifiers.

**Logged Utility Stream**
Similar to a data stream, but operations are logged to the NTFS log file just like NTFS metadata changes. This is used by EFS.

**Reparse Point**
Used for volume mount points. They are also used by Installable File System (IFS) filter drivers to mark certain files as special to that driver.

**Index Root**
Used to implement folders and other indexes.

**Index Allocation**
Used to implement folders and other indexes.

**Bitmap**
Used to implement folders and other indexes.

**Volume Information**
Used only in the $Volume system file. Contains the volume version.

**Volume Name** 
Used only in the $Volume system file. Contains the volume label.

The best tool for viewing this data is [ntfswalk](https://tzworks.net/prototype_page.php?proto_id=12)

Another good resource is [An introduction to NTFS](https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/IntNTFSfs.htm)